# How much cooling is my mist maker humidifier causing?

Tags: hvac, humidifier

Closely related to [Does a humidifier cool the air?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/24859/does-a-humidifier-cool-the-air) but with a different kind of humidifier, and I'd like to know exact numbers.

First question: for the same production volume of vapor, does an ultrasonic mist maker cause the same amount of cooling as an evaporative humidifier?

Second, more practical question: My apartment already struggles sometimes with keeping the unit warm, but it's also far too dry, so I need to humidify. I bought a mist maker with stated vaporizing capacity of 1600ml/h.
[image: Mist maker]

It seems since I've had it running, the heater struggles even more than before. How do I convert from ml/h to BTUs I am losing to humidification? Do I need to provide other parameters (like a starting relative humidity and temperature)? I looked at Philip's chart at: http://www.truetex.com/psychrometric_chart.gif but I'm not really sure how to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking about is the *latent heat of vaporization*.

It is 970 real BTUs per pound of water, or 2260 joules per gram.   A joule is a watt-second.  A BTU raises one pound of water one degree F.

That means if you have an ugly bag of liquid water, 1 pound, and it is 112F temperature, and you inject 100 BTU, it is now 212F.  If you inject another 970 BTU, it is still 212F but is now vapor.  If you inject 30 more BTU to make it an even thousand, it is now 242F.  The 970 BTU was *eaten* by the phase change.   Yes, you can use this to air-condition, but it works better with freon, propane, etc.

There's no free lunch.  That energy has to come from somewhere.

A gallon of water is 3785 grams (also 3785 ml, by *wild coincidence, not*). It will take 8.5 million joules or 2400 watt-hours, or 8200 real BTU,  to evaporate it.   If the humidifier avoids paying it (e.g. By misting), it is stolen from the air, cooling the air.

By "real BTU" I mean BTU is a timeless unit.  Remember when a furnace talks about BTU, that is slang. It actually means BTU/hr.

Comment: Thanks for the hard numbers! The mister uses 350W of electricity. If I run it for an hour, vaporizing 1600ml water, that requires 1004 watt-hours. Do I subtracted 350 watt-hours from that to get the amount of heat that was taken from the air to make up the difference?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: @Harper well said! Your ability to describe things is impeccable.

Comment: @Harper do you have any teaching or instructor background?

Comment: @JoeFala no, but thanks.

Comment: Okay so it will cool the air locally but as it doesn't change the amount of energy in the structure so at some point the humidified air will return to equilibrium and thus gives no net change in temperature in the structure. Water is one of the best refrigerants know because of its high heat capacity the problem with it (as a refrigerant) is it's an excellent solvent and it has a high fusion (freezing) temperature. A cooling system relocates the heat to outdoors through the latent effect. A local cooling effect is observed but overall it heats. It's similar to running a table top fan.Continued

Comment: A fan has a heating effect that is directly proportional to it's current draw. My best Air conditioning salesman is an army of fans in someone's house. It's like running the stove in the dead of summer. At first it feels cool but it adds so much heat eventually people buckle and buy a brand new A/C. An air conditioners primary function is to remove moisture. If the condenser was inside the house and the condensate was allowed to evaporate back into the air the net effect would be heating but the air blowing out of the ducts would be cool.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I love your answer and it's better and more clear then mine I just really like the subject.

Comment: "at some point the humidified air will return to equilibrium" - are you referring to air exchange with the outside? It is a pretty leaky apartment: I estimate I need about 15GPD to humidify the whole thing. So the cooling effect of the humidifier is actually added to the cooling effect of air exchange (because the air outside is much colder).

Comment: @JoeFala it doesn't change the total amount of energy in the structure, but evaporating water does convert some of that energy into *latent heat of vaporization*, so the practical temperature in the room goes down.   This is how sweat works.  It is also why propane tanks get frosty.

Comment: @Matt Chambers and Harper I don't know how to word this but think about like this. The humidifier goes to the "heat bank" and borrows 970 btus to vaporize 1lb of water. If the heat isn't removed from the building it has to be paid back because the energy hasn't left the building. The cost of borrowing is the added heat of the humidifier running.

Comment: Propane tanks get cool because you are removing vapour and as you know vapor has a much higher heat content thanks to the all that latent heat in it. If you were to shake a closed propane tank it would have more vapor pressure because of the added energy from the shaking and thus more heat.

Comment: @JoeFala if one pound of water vapor leaves the building, it takes the 970 BTU with it.  In the propane tank, as you remove vapor, you lower the vapor pressure.  That compels more propane to boil, and it extracts its latent heat of vaporization by chilling the liquid.

Comment: @Harper exactly, in the case of the ultrasonic humidifier nothing is leaving the building, so it's more like the shaken propane tank. Net positive energy.

Comment: But due to air exchange in a leaky building, the warm humidified air is constantly being exchanged with cold, dry (in absolute terms) air outside the building.

Comment: @Matt Chambers that is a fact, the term is "infiltration air" and the loosest envelops are about 1 change per 2 hours and the tightest are about 2/day. The average house is about 1/6 hours. I did the math on your unit and it comes to (assuming 70*F water) 3927.63btu minus 1194.25 for the power input we get 2733.38btu/h which is .228 tons of cooling. That is quite substantial. If we assume 1 air change per 3 hours you will be losing 911.128 btu/h. I've never had to think about it this way. It's trickier when you factor outside RH and indoor RH and how you feel 10% RH vs 35% RH but I'm humbled.

Answer (score 1):

Technically a humidifier heats the air but it's not in the form of a temperature change. Well it sort of is. It's a little complicated but it adds latent heat and also reduces evaporation from your body making you feel warmer. It's different than misting water on your body. In that case water deposited on your body will evaporat due to the difference in moisture levels of your body and the air. The evaporating water must take heat energy with it. It's a very fascinating but unfortunately overlooked subject. The rabbit hole goes very deep for this one but I could talk about it all day. The enthalpy chart in your link will only confuse the average laymen and even most professionals.

Comment: _The evaporating water must take heat energy with it._
That's what I'm curious about. How much heat energy is it taking out of the air (putting into latent heat) to put moisture into it? Our skin can't feel (and a the thermometer can't measure) that latent heat, right?

Comment: Yes it does and that is coming from the mister, the remaining energy of evaporation from the air does not leave or disappear. So the net effect is an increase of btu

Comment: In this case it's not a big increase but it's not a negative effect

Comment: The body can feel latent heat due to the evaporation effect but a thermometer cannot unless it is a sling psychrometer or a digital hygrometer

Comment: I'm actually at in a customer's driveway I'll be back, but Google things like sling psychrometer, wet-bulb and dry bulb, and relative humidity.